# Jquery Mobile swipe event through div elements

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on an app using `phonegap` and `jquery-mobile` that has a layout that is simply two rows of data and about 50 columns in a table. *I want each horizontal swipe to show the next respective column and each vertical swipe to show the respective 2nd row connected with each 1st row column.*

Example:

```
divA1  divB1  divC1  divD1  divE1  divF1  divG1  divH1  divI1  divJ1
divA2  divB2  divC2  divD2  divE2  divF2  divG2  divH2  divI2  divJ2
```

With each horizontal swipe showing the next div in line and a vertical swipe revealing the 2div below it.

I understand how to swipe between different pages as a form of navigation (using `data-role="page"`)but,

I am looking to achieve this similar functionality with a list of divs and I have yet to find anything explaining how to achieve this.

Thanks for any help you can provide or an available plugin solution to achieve this.

Comment: Pages are just divs. If these are fixed data, why not make a page for each div?

Comment: Well the content in each div will change constantly and being there is up to 400 or so different divs I dont think it would make sense to create individual pages that will be the exact same except for the content in the divs.

Comment: You can and should create pages dynamically, of course.

Comment: Actually, it might even work with a single page and just changing its content dynamically. I'm not sure right now if this will work with the transitions, but there definitely should be a way. Might be less trouble than creating actual page divs on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you should explore is known as a *sprite sheet*. You should put all your `divs` on a single container `div` on the layer/page. You then use dynamically controlled `.style` changing, to reposition the `div` container relative to the viewports `.offset`, based on the direction of the swipe. So for example if the individual `divs` are `width:100px` each, then a left swipe event should produce:

```
var el=document.getElementById("divContainer");
el.style.cssText ='left:'+ (el.offsetLeft-100) + 'px';
```

A right swipe would add to the positioning:

`(el.offsetLeft+100)`

Up/down would follow the same logic:

```
el.style.cssText ='top:'+ (offset top +/- positioning) + 'px';
```